# Is it possible to create a "Positive Number" type in Swift?

Tags: swift, types, static-analysis

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm wondering if there's a way in Swift to create a type that exclusively holds numbers that are strictly greater than zero and where the "positiveness" of the values is enforced at compile time.

For example, can I create somehow write code like

```
func divide(x: PositiveNumber, y: PositiveNumber){
    return x / y
}
```

such that

```
divide(1, 3)
```

works but

```
divide(1, 0)
```

won't compile?

The closest thing I could come up with was a struct with only one fallible initializer such that the type has either a positive value or is nil:

```
struct PositiveNumber {
    let value: Float

    init?(value: Float){
        if value > 0 {
            self.value = value
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

func / (left: PositiveNumber, right: PositiveNumber) -> Float {
    return left.value / right.value
}

func divide(x: PositiveNumber?, y: PositiveNumber?) -> Float? {
    if let x = x, y = y {
        return x / y
    }
    return nil
}

let x1 = PositiveNumber(value: 1)
let y1 = PositiveNumber(value: 3)

let x2 = PositiveNumber(value: -1)
let y2 = PositiveNumber(value: 0)

divide(x1, y: y1)!  // .333
divide(x2, y: y2)!  // runtime error
```

That's not terrible but we still have to deal with a lot of optional handling/unwrapping. I'm asking this question because I have many places in my code where I need to check that a value is not zero and I'm curious if there's a way to remove that code and let the compiler handle it. The struct-based solution requires pretty much the same amount of code.

Comment: maybe accept some answers or respond to active comments until the issue is resolved, thx

Comment: The best current answer is "it's impossible" so I'm holding out hoping that someone has an "it's possible" answer. If none appear soon I'll close the question.

Comment: You do also realise that it is impossible to know any value that isn't static before runtime. So checking for `0` when compiling is impossible. Still I would like to see the actual issue, maybe there is a work around.

Answer (score 1):

[Number Type build on Float](https://gist.github.com/romainmenke/93332ab7f5824caafa17)

This gist is contains a Struct that conforms to pretty much everything Float conforms too. It is just a vanilla copy of Float, change it to your liking.

---

**Have you considered a custom operator?**

```
infix operator /+ { associativity left precedence 150 }

func /+(lhs:Float,rhs:Float) -> Float? {

    guard rhs > 0 else {
        return nil
    }
    return lhs / rhs
}

let test = 2 /+ -1 // nil
let test2 = 2 /+ 1 // 2

let test3 = 2 /+ 1 + 2 // warning
```

It doesn't really matter if you let it return an optional, or an enum value, or different protocols. You will have to handle the return. But this way you get compiler warnings.

---

**Limited Number Type with just an operator to handle divisions:**

You could change math altogether and create a PositiveNumber Type that returns NaN when dividing by a value less than Zero.

```
public struct PositiveFloat {
    public var value: Float
    /// Create an instance initialized to zero.
    public init() {
        self.value = 0
    }
    /// Create an instance initialized to `value`.
    public init(_ value: Float) {
        self.value = value
    }

    public init(_ value: PositiveFloat) {
        self.value = value.value
    }
}

extension Float {
    public var positive : PositiveFloat {
        return PositiveFloat(self)
    }
}


public func /(lhs:Float,rhs:PositiveFloat) -> Float {
    if 0 > rhs.value {
        return lhs / rhs.value
    } else {
        return Float.NaN
    }
}
public func /(lhs:PositiveFloat,rhs:PositiveFloat) -> Float {
    if 0 > rhs.value {
        return lhs.value / rhs.value
    } else {
        return Float.NaN
    }
}
```

---

```
let testNormal : Float = 10
let testFloat : Float = -5

let test = testFloat / testNormal.positive
if test.isNaN {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting direction. In my particular case, division by zero is not the actual problem I'm worried about. (I was trying to use it as an illustrative example). My specific problem is that I have a legacy system I'm working with that treats zero as a special case so the code has tons of `if x == 0 { error } else { doStuff }`. My hope is that I can find a way to use the compiler to enforce that x is not zero so I can remove all that error handling code.