# Enforce valid integer values at compile time in Swift

Tags: swift

In a Swift app I have a function that only accepts integers between +2 and positive infinity. Is there any way to enforce this at compile time?

Updated with a small code sample:

To calculate a Fibonacci sequence we need at least two numbers to start with, anything else is an error. Here I use guard and an failable initializer to verify this at runtime.

```
struct FibonacciSeed {

    var magnitude = 2

    init() { }

    init?( magnitude: Int ) {

        guard magnitude > 1 else { return nil }

        self.magnitude = magnitude

    }

    var seed: [Int] {

        // return valid seed ...

    }

}
```

I was curious if there were some fancy way to enlist the help of the compiler to enforce this at compile time. Like the compiler doesn't let me compile:

```
var a:UInt = -8
```

Comment: Maybe post some code, so that we can help you more easily.  But no, there isn't, and it would be bad if there was. If the compiler would have to anticipate all possible values it would take forever to build. (literally)

Comment: This is similar : [enforce positive Float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34260199/is-it-possible-to-create-a-positive-number-type-in-swift/34260844#34260844)

Comment: The wording of your question doesn't seem right. There's no way to write such a function. Your function accepts an integer argument - You probably want to find a way to enforce a constraint that the argument is greater than 2. It's impossible at compile time, but the `guard` statement is probably a good way to do this at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Updated with a code example (with an initializer function). You are probably right that this can't be done at compile time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature in Swift. Compiler cannot know at compile time what kind of values the application passes to functions at runtime. As a runtime feature it would just make the Swift runtime libraries bigger. That would make applications bigger even if they don't use the specific feature. I'm quite sure Apple want to keep the libraries as small as possible.

Comment: I'm sure you'r right. Was just curios if there, in Apples new ProtocolOriented paradigm, were som new protocol or anything that could be implemented that only allowed certain numbers to be asigned to a variable. Like Swift only allows positive literal integers to be assigned to a variable of the type Uint. Thanks for the response!